# Looking for description of Helstrom's measurement

Tags: specific-reference, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I hope someone can help me find the page or chapter where Helstrom discusses his famous measurement for distinguishing between two mixtures in the textbook *Quantum Detection and Estimation Theory*.

Thanks in advance.